# Passing Two Optional parameter to RedirectToRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

I am passing 2 nullable parameters to a Products action. However I am forced to pass some value in `mallId`, otherwise I get a `no route table matches found` error. I want to pass `null` in `mallId` and receive in the `Products` action.

```
return RedirectToRoute("Products",
                      new
                      {   
                          mallId =(Int32?)null,
                          storeId =(Int32?)storeProducts.StoreId
                      });


[Route("Mall/{mallId?}/Store/{storeId?}/Products", Name = "Products")]
public ActionResult Products(string mallId, long? storeId)
{
    return View(products);
}
```

Attribute routing is cracking my head but it is great too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[Route("Mall/{mallId?}/Store/{storeId?}/Products", Name = "Products")]
public ActionResult Products(string mallId = null, long? storeId)
{
    return View(products);
}
```

and don't pass in a value for mallId

Answer (score 2):

You should provide a default value for mallId. The way you distribute the parameters makes impossible to not provide the mallId in the route composition:

```
[Route("Mall/{mallId=all}/Store/{storeId?}/Products", Name = "Products")]
public ActionResult Products(string mallId = "all", long? storeId = null)
{
    if(mallId == "all")
       //do something

    return View(products);
}
```

Comment: both answer works. Upvoted.Thanks. Accepting first one